# react-router v4 doesn't trigger routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use react-router v4 and for some reason when I change the routes using normal links and the Link components, the route doesn't trigger, but if I access directly in the URL bar or just refresh the page, the component from that route renders the component. After inspect, I've saw that the context is updated but the props not. As you can see in the image below:
[image: code-situation]
Started at the '/about' route, clicked the '/projects' Link (the AboutMe component stills inside the Switch, instead of change for the Projects component). The routes are defined like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route path='/about' component={AboutMe}/>
    <Route path='/projects' component={Projects}/>
    <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
    <Route component={NotFound} />
 </Switch>
```

I've already tried using the BrowserRouter, HashRouter and just the Router components and also with/without wrapping the routes in the Switch component (nothing seems to work).
I'm already after two days searching in tutorials, in the docs, other stackoverflow questions and in the repo issues, and found nothing so far, so here I'm! :)

I'm using these packages:

- react v15.5.4
- react-router-dom v4.1.1

Thanks in advance! \o

Comment: It looks like you're also using Redux and React-Redux - could it be that Redux is (rightly) noticing the state in the store hasn't changed, and therefore (confusingly) deciding not to re-render?

Comment: Yep, I've just removed all related from react-router-redux (doesn't work with react-router v4) and the sync of the route state with the store to see if it works, still the same :(
I'll try remove the Provider and see what happens :)
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Exactly @WanderNauta, the router didn't saw the changes in the store so it didn't updated. I've removed the Provider and everything worked fine :)
So basically, as react-router-redux don't work with the v4, I'll have to implement the actions and reducers for each router by myself :/